# Wing Chun Buddhism Zen Stance - Standing Meditation

Tags: meditation

I understand the Martial Arts namely Wing Chun basic stance has a form of meditation.

I understand Grand master Yip Man or Bruce Lee's master already modified it so it's easier to be absorbed and learned by public. Qi Gong or breathing technique been removed from syllabus as i understand.

There are too many versions and theories about this stance and breathing/meditation technique when i search online.

Anyone can share the closest original info about this stance meditation and breathing technique? [image]

[image]

Comment: This question might be on-topic at https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/ Incidentally my Tai Chi teacher told me to also hold my "neck straight", and not to stick my chin out like that. The "knees bent and hips tilted forward" looks familiar to me -- that straightens/undoes the S-curve (i.e. lordosis) in the spine -- but the cocked fists look strange to me, perhaps like karate or something like that.

Comment: @Chrisw just close this if found inappropriate. Since this martial arts came from Shaolin then I would expect meditation shall come from origin from Buddhism too for study else I would not dare to practice. It could be a reason too Yip Man removed this breathing technique from his syllabus due to insufficient info or guide. Personally experience some odd side effect from this practices but now ok.

Comment: Let me post this on martial arts exhange soon

Answer (score 2):

This is just another form of nei gong - not much different than Zhan Zhuang (standing post).  It has some things in common with samatha meditation namely the interplay of relaxation and upright posture.  It's good stuff, don't get me wrong, but it is limited as to the degree of one pointedness one can achieve at least as compared to sitting meditation.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely derived form 経行 (Jap. *kin-hin*, Chin. jīngxíng) literally means "walking meditation". It  is a practice within several forms of Buddhism that involve movement and periods of walking between long periods of sitting meditation. During walking meditation each step is taken after each full breath.

The practice is common in *Chan* Buddhism and its extra-Chinese forms, *Zen*, Korean *Seon* and Vietnamese *Thiền*.